# Does this code cause memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am curious if this code causes memory
leak probably due to the fact that I reassign
the pointer at line 3 before deleting it at line 4??

Thanks.

```
1. int y = 12;
2. int *pt = new int;
3. pt = &y;
4. delete pt;
```

Comment: I think it crashes cause pt is not pointing to the reserver memory space anymore

Comment: Your code will more likely crash...

Comment: @DGomez, Doesn't have to. It's UB.

Comment: I would like to reply to ppl here: yes, indeed it crashes

Comment: Well, of course it *can*. It just doesn't have to. Consider yourself lucky it did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It not only leaks the dynamically allocated `int` but also has undefined behaviour, because you can't `delete` an object that wasn't allocated with `new` (§5.3.5/2).

> the value of the operand of `delete` may be a null pointer value, a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous *new-expression*, or a pointer to a subobject (1.8) representing a base class of such an object (Clause 10). If not, the behavior is undefined.

Since the object denoted by `y` was not allocated with a *new-expression*, you cannot use `delete` to destroy it. Its lifetime is governed by its scope.

Comment: So I should be careful when reassigning pointers? I've heard in C this was an issue, didn't experience it in C++ though.

Comment: @user2054339 You should be careful with pointers in general. A raw pointer type says very little about the lifetime of the object it points to. Prefer to use smart pointers, which are much clearer.

Comment: Would this be a correct way (I know may be not elegant but still) to delete p1 and p2?
` int *y;
 int *p1 = new int;
 int *p2 = new int;
 y = p1;
 delete y;
 y=p2;
 delete y;`

Comment: @user2054339 That would work, but it's hideous. Better: `int p1; int p2;` and don't even worry about deallocation.

Comment: @user2054339: Don't say `new` for stuff you're going to delete in the same block of code.  That's what auto storage (ie: a local variable) is for.

Comment: @cHao - Yes, I see I was just experimenting trying to see how the delete works (also with my comment above to @sftrabbit)

Comment: So I should not reassign a pointer if it was pointing to smth else before?

Comment: @user2054339 Well you can do if you know what you're doing. As long as you still have some way to `delete` the object and eventually do, it can be fine.

Comment: @user2054339: You can reassign pointers.  Just keep track of them, and don't *lose* them.  `delete` a pointer, xor know that there's a copy of it elsewhere, before you reassign it.  Really, though, i'd suggest learning about smart pointers and using them instead in 99% of all cases.  If you do it right, the only code that will ever have to `delete` anything are the smart pointer classes themselves.  Resolves a few other issues as well; with a decent smart pointer library, you get better exception safety pretty much for free.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you are not sure about memory leaks in your code, you can use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) `valgrind --tool=memcheck` to check for them, but be sure to compile the code without any optimization and in full debug mode (e.g. "g++ -g").

Here is the output for your program:

```
=29667== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==29667== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==29667== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==29667== Command: ./main
==29667== 
==29667== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
==29667==    at 0x4C26DCF: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:387)
==29667==    by 0x4006AB: main (main.cpp:7)
==29667==  Address 0x7fefffd0c is on thread 1's stack
==29667== 
==29667== 
==29667== HEAP SUMMARY:
==29667==     in use at exit: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==29667==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 4 bytes allocated
==29667== 
==29667== LEAK SUMMARY:
==29667==    definitely lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==29667==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29667==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29667==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29667==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29667== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==29667== 
==29667== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==29667== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

Your code looses 4 bytes at exit().

Here is the list of stuff you can do with memcheck, from the tool's [website](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html)

> Memcheck is a memory error detector. It can detect the following
>   problems that are common in C and C++ programs.
>
> - Accessing memory you shouldn't, e.g. overrunning and 
>     underrunning heap blocks, overrunning the top of the stack, and accessing memory
>     after it has been freed.
> - Using undefined values, i.e. values that have not been initialised, 
>     or that have been derived from other undefined values.
> - Incorrect freeing of heap memory, such as double-freeing heap blocks, 
>     or mismatched use of malloc/new/new[] versus
>     free/delete/delete[]
>
>   - Overlapping src and dst pointers in memcpy and related functions.
>   - Memory leaks.
>
> **Problems like these can be difficult to find by other means**, often
>   remaining undetected for long periods, then causing occasional,
>   difficult-to-diagnose crashes.

Comment: Kudos for showing valgrind and the usage. But this experiment isn't helpful in the sense that his code also contains undefined behavior (by calling `delete` on something that was not allocated by `new`) which means anything goes after that.

Comment: @NikBougalis Valgrind detects the invalid `delete`: you can see it in the output there. If that's not helpful I don't know what is.

Comment: I don't disagree - it was helpful here and I should have been more careful in my phrasing. But my main point was that once you hit undefined behavior *anything* goes, and that's why UB **must** be pointed out explicitly to the OP. With UB in the game, it's *possible* that valgrind could have came back with "no memory leaked, you're *golden*" or even with something beginning with "Hey sexy..."

Answer (score 2):

It would cause a memory leak if it didn't first likely cause a crash.

You shouldn't delete an object that has 'automatic' storage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The moment you lost the pointer to the `new` `int` you leaked

```
pt = &y; // Here the memory allocated is not reachable now and can not be deleted
```

And this is UB

```
delete pt;  // pt is pointing to automaticaly allocated memory now. You can't delete that.
```

Comment: Probably cause you didn't mention the UB aspect.  If the program even *survives* deleting an auto object, then yes, there's *probably* a leak...but the second that `delete` happens, the program's run off the rails.  There's no point in even *trying* to reason about behavior beyond that point.

Comment: @cHao Yes I was editing. You know answer and edit. but Even then OP asked about leak so the answer might not be complete but doesn't deserve -1 I think.

Comment: @Named: I don't approve of the FGITW stuff, so no sympathy from me there.  :)  But yeah, downvoting may be a bit harsh

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that an eventual crash is likely in most implementations of C++, even if the behavior is undefined per the spec.  In fact, an immediate crash is probably the best case you could hope for - some implementations would corrupt the heap in this case, causing a crash (or worse) far from the source of the problem.  In any case, the down vote is inappropriate.

Comment: If you do submit an answer before you've finished writing it, you can't really complain when someone based on the answer they can see.

Comment: @MichaelPrice: You shouldn't give sympathy upvotes.. that's not how voting works. When you press the downvote button, it says, "This answer is __not__ useful." Consider that for a second.

Comment: @DanHulme Ya I guess. But it was complete as far as OP's question goes. As was everyone else's

Comment: @cHao Just googled FGITW and found the meaning on meta. Who knew :)

Answer (score 0):

It should crash, because you assing a stack adress to your pointer and then delete it. At least it's undefined what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does indeed cause a memory leak because the subsequent assignment of `pt` causes you to lose the previous assignment that contained the memory. If you had called `delete pt` before that, it would have been fine.